# The user name remains displayed when selecting another site (tablet device only)

Tags: bug, android-app

When selecting a new site in the app, the user name remains displayed in the bar above.

[image]

## How to reproduce:

1. Look at a user's profile.
2. Click "All (number) sites"
3. Click one of the icons that are displayed in the left.

The user name at the top remains displayed.

---

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: asus
- Device Model: K011

  - OS Version: 4.4.2 (JP_K011-JP_user_3.1.23.189_20141124-user-20141124)

Comment: What is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: As title, "The user name remain displaying". See also Picture.

Comment: I see the picture and title, but not sure what the problem is., I can't see an issue, that's why I was asking for clarification

Comment: I through disappeared the user name. but that still remains.

Comment: Can't reproduce, is your device a tablet? Maybe it behaves in a different way when there is a wide screen.

Comment: I'm using [tablet](https://www.asus.com/Tablets/ASUS_MeMO_Pad_8_ME181C/).

Answer (score -1):

This is intended behavior.

When you click on that icon on the left, what you get is *that particular user's* page for the site you selected. So the user's name should remain on top.

Comment: Thing is, you see all the site questions, not the user's. That's the bug.